# AWS Appsync - listTodos function returns 'Undefined' error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am following below mentioned tutorial to implement a basic AWS App sync javascript app.

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/start?platform=purejs

However, when I run my app I am getting 'Undefined' error from my async function of listTodos

```
import API, { graphqlOperation } from '@aws-amplify/api'
import * as queries from './graphql/queries';

import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
API.configure(awsconfig);

async function listTodos1() {

try {
    const allTodos1 = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.listTodos));
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}

}


listTodos1();
```

I am new to JS and not sure how to debug further.

I have already implemented an android app using AWS appsync and I have done basic graphql related debugging but stuck with this issue.

Comment: This issue was due to wrong authentication mechanism. issue is now resolved.

Comment: Can you explain in detail, how you resolved this issue pls. I am stuck with the same error